# Log a template message every time I commit in Git

Tags: git, shell, git-commit, githooks

I am making my own template that involves my a bit of custom git hooks. I opened the hooks folder, and everything was a `.sample` file which I know nothing about.

What I am doing is manipulating the `commit-msg.sample` file in my hooks folder, and I messed it up... My textbook stated: "We'll use the commit-msg hook as the example hook:"

```bash
#!/bin/sh
MSG_FILE="$1"
echo "\nHi from the template commit-msg hook" >> $MSG_FILE
```

I decided that I would manipulate the file manually, and my file `commit-msg.sample` file looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
MSG_FILE="$1"
"\nHi from the template commit-msg hook" >> $MSG_FILE
# a bunch of comments....
MSG_FILE="$1"

test "" = "$(grep '^Signed-off-by: ' "$1" |
     sort | uniq -c | sed -e '/^[   ]*1[    ]/d')" || {
    echo >&2 \nHi from the template commit-msg hook  >> $MSG_FILE
    exit 1
}
```

However, when I do `git log -1`, I end up with the default and no `"\nHi from the template commit-msg hook".` I want it so that whenever I do `git log -1`, it also displays that message.

What am I doing wrong here? Any explanation would be great.

Here is my reproductible example:

1. Create a `.git_template` directory
2. Add a hooks and info folder
3. Copy and paste all the files from hooks and info folders in the default directory (usually the  `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) and put them into the `.git_template` 's hooks and and info directories respectively
4. Now in the `.git_template/hooks` you should find a `commit-msg.sample`.
5. below `#!/bin/sh`, delete everything else and write down

`echo "\nHi from the template commit-msg hook" >> $MSG_FILE`

6. In the terminal, do the `chmod +x commit-msg.sample`
7. Using the absolute file path, do the following command.

`git config --global init.templatedir [ABSOLUTE PATH]/.git_template`

8. In a completely new folder, initialize a git repository. Add anything say index.js then do `git add *` then `git commit -m "my message"`
9. Now do `git log -1`
10. Now the expected output is "my message \nHi from the template commit-msg hook". Basically it's supposed to be the git commit message plus the hook's message. However, I only get the git commit message which is "my message".

If there's a step that I did wrong, please let me know.

Comment: `"\nHi from the template commit-msg hook" >> $MSG_FILE` is missing something important -- like an `echo` or (better) a `printf`. `"some-string" >>file` doesn't write the string `some-string`; instead, it tries to find a _command_ named `some-string`.

Comment: Also, using both `>&2` and `>>"$MSG_FILE"` on the same simple command doesn't make sense. Stdout can go to stderr, _or_ it can go to a file; it can't go both places at once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so should I remove the what looks like the test function and on the 3rd line, put `echo`?

Comment: What should the program do? Log to a file?

Comment: @Guildenstern when I do `git log -1`, it should print out `"\nHi from the template commit-msg hook"` along with the commit details.

Comment: Also, keep in mind I am using bash on Windows

Comment: Could you consider making this a [mre] -- building only the _smallest possible_ example that reproduces the problem? If the `grep | sort | uniq | sed` pipeline isn't actually part of your problem, can you take it out to make a smaller example that still has different behavior from what you expect? Right now there are enough moving parts that it's difficult to understand exactly what behavior you expect from your script, and thus exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry for the late reply, had to travel. Anyways, I provided an example, is there any other edits you would like for me to make?

Comment: I ended up fixing it. I realized I had to remove the `.sample` extension !!!